# Shrinking Git Repo - Object in packet, not in commits

Tags: git, git-rewrite-history, git-rev-list, git-verify-pack

I'm trying to shrink a Git repo that's around 2GB.

I'm following the "Removing Objects" section of Chapter 9 (9.7) in the ProGit book:
http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Maintenance-and-Data-Recovery

After running `git gc`, then a `git verify-pack` and `git rev-list` command, I've found a `.tar` file that's about 118MB. I don't need it to be in my repo at all. It needs destroying forever.

But when I try to find out which commits have used that file, I get nothing:

```
git log --oneline -- news/news.tar
```

Does this mean the file is not in the repository history? And if that's the case can I just leave it or will it still get pushed up as an object when I do `git push`?

If that's the case, how do I get rid of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Use The BFG, not git-filter-branch...

The BFG gives a foolproof method of getting rid of large files, much easier than using `git filter-branch`, see http://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/ :

```
$ bfg  --strip-blobs-bigger-than 100M  my-repo.git
```

### ...still here?

If you'd like to try to figure out what's gone awry when you were following the steps from "Removing Objects" in section 9.7 of the ProGit book, there are unfortunately several places where it's possible to go wrong.

The `news.tar` file is currently kept by one of your branches, tags or some other kind of ref - we know this because the file showed up when you ran `git rev-list --objects --all` (the '--all' param means look at *all* refs, beyond just branches - tags, and other exotic types of ref) ...but your `git log --oneline -- news/news.tar` command does not have an `--all`, it's just listing your current branch. Your blob is being held by a different reference- probably a different branch or tag.

Seriously, just use The BFG.

*Full disclosure: I'm the author of the BFG Repo-Cleaner.*

Comment: Thanks, I've been looking at BFG, but it doesn't work with paths, so I don't think I can use it. I wanted to use the `--delete-files` command, but I've got a large image (somehow a 60Mb JPG got in the repo) but a smaller version of the file, with the same name, exist elsewhere.

Comment: It's working great for files that I know there are only one of though

Comment: AAAAAAH I've just found this:  --strip-blobs-with-ids. That might do it

Comment: OK, I've used BFG and it's great but the docs are a little thin. I found the extra options I need by running my `bfg` alias with no extra commands. I've used the wildcards with `--delete-files`, and a  list of blogs of specific files and paths which I used with ` --strip-blobs-with-ids`

Comment: Fair enough, glad it's been of use to you! Just so I know, what factor stopped you from using the `--strip-blobs-bigger-than` option?

Comment: I don't feel confident deleting blobs over a certain size - there are some larger files that I want to keep their history.

Comment: Checking out my repo is still massive and size. I check the git logs and I see that the file was removed, but when I check it out, it's still there.

Comment: Wow, using BFG even cleaned/fixed the changes in my history, which the incorrect usage of filter-branch introduced! This deserves way more upvotes to get the attention it deserves.